# Networking is disabled and I can't re-enable it

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

For some reason I seem to get disconnected from my wifi as noted by the nm-applet going to the disconnected icon. When I hover the mouse it says networking disabled. When I click on enable networking, nothing happens and I am forced to reboot to get my wifi back.

```
kreuger@Robbies-Laptop:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

kreuger@Robbies-Laptop:~$ rfkill list  
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  

kreuger@Robbies-Laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux Robbies-Laptop 3.13.0-58-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 8 02:56:50 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Not sure why it says i686 so many times.

Comment: Try `rfkill unblock`. It also might be a problem with the network manager. Download `Wicd Network Manager` from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I used wicd for a while but for some reason (I don't remember why now) it stopped working.

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? And output of `uname -r`.

Comment: I've been using WICD lately and for some reason it's allowing me to connect but nothing loads. When I try to reconnect, sometimes it tells me the password is bad even though I haven't changed it. And when I try to use nm-applet instead, it says "device not ready"

Answer (score 26):

try these commands

These commands will delete the file where network state is stored and restarts the service forcefuly.

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Don't post code without any explanation about why and how it helps.

Comment: Ok, this, as barbaric as `sudo -f` could look, seem to definitely work for eth/wlan disappear with the same driver  on 16LTS; good job

Comment: @cafebabe1991 -- thank you man it works for me after struggling for almost 1 hr without internet

Comment: to restart the networking, is it important to delete the state file?

Comment: This works for me.  For the record, (on Ubuntu 14.04.5 32-bit), all I have to do is to restart the network-manager service.  No need to remove the state file

Answer (score 4):

This command solved for me:

```
sudo nmcli n on
```

`nmcli` is the network manager client, `n` stands for *networking* and `on` means that the command must turn networking back on.

If the command above does not solve the issue, run this command:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

...and then run `sudo nmcli n on` again.